# Ubuntu 16.10 upgrade Unity8 fails to login

Tags: unity8, 16.10

I upgraded 16.04 to 16.10 and wanted to try unity8. 
 In the login screen when i select "unity8" and enter password the screen stay as is and nothing happens 
*screenshot attached

**What should i do? Where can i get the logs that are being using to investigate whats going on
[image]

Comment: Same here... Have to reboot.

Comment: :) you think I didn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read so far the reason behind that is in missing support of features used in Unity by Nvidia drivers.
I could try to switch to intel driver just for the sake of the test, but decided it's not worth the effort.

So far it's unclear when NVidia will properly support U8, at least I didn't find any specific date

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend just purging the hideous nightmare that comprises Unity 8 entirely using
sudo autoremove --purge unity8
which will uninstall all the main unnecessary components of the Unity 8 preview. I'm running 16.10 perfectly fine without it.

Comment: The Unity 8 desktop preview is completely unusable on my high DPI laptop display, and looks positively awful. So yes, it's a nightmare. My main desktop also seems to change in scaling whenever I switch back, so I figured it was useless and decided to free up some memory by just purging it. Mostly because...it's awful.

Comment: will consider that

Comment: How would OP do that if he can't log in? -1

Comment: Use the rescue shell on startup by booting into recovery mode.

Comment: Won't there be no desktop at all then?

Comment: Um...no. Just uninstall the problematic Unity 8 preview. The normal Unity 7 used in the main desktop will be unaffected. The Unity 8 preview is buggy and incomplete as hell.